# raspi-config network option not working

Tags: wifi, pi-2, raspbian-stretch, raspi-config

I am trying to turn on the network option in raspi-config, but when I do, I get this error:

```
could not communicate with wpa_supplicant
```

Then I hit enter to continue and I get this message

```
There was an error running option N2 Wi-Fi
```

I am running the newest version of Rasbian. I am also using an Edimax usb Wi-Fi adapter through a USB port on my pi.

Comment: Which model raspberry pi is it? B, A, 2B, 3B, 3B+, 3A+, Zero, Zero W?

Comment: I am using a 2B

Comment: I am using 3B+, so my suggestion might not work for 2B.  Now I am thinking of using a 2B with a Wifi dongle to talk to my 3B.  So I need to do installation for both Rpis.  I am changing my old answer to show what I am going to experiment.  You might like to comment and I am happy to make changes.

Comment: @Mooshroom14 I found 2B with Raspbian 2019Apr can detect the TP-LINK dongle.  No need to install any driver.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of these commands: `iw dev` and `sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` but obscure the password.

Answer (score 7):

Try run wpa_supplicant interactively:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d -iwlan0
```

This will provide a lot of diagnostic logging; in my case (using a USB Wifi dongle), "Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands". Once I downloaded the off-kernel driver, wpa_supplicant worked fine and **so did raspi-config's N2 configuration**.

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400101/how-to-get-the-wifi-working-with-r8188eu-driver-on-my-raspberry-pi

Comment: Running `wpa_supplicant` interactively is a very useful way of debugging.  This just helped me fix an issue with a character that looked like an apostrophe but which wasn't.

Comment: this should be in the official documentation.

Comment: That saved my day!
After trying a bunch of solutions I had an error with the apostrophe as well !!

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

How to use Raspbian version 2019 April to config WiFi for Rpi 2B?

***Answer***

*Introduction*

The OP has a Rpi2B with a WiFi dongle.  He has a problem configing Wifi.  This answer has two parts:

> 1. Install Raspbian on 3B+ and config Wifi.
> 2. Use the same SD card to config the 2B.

*Setting up Rpi2B with a Wifi Dongle*

[image: rpi2b and wifi dongle]

*Preparing a micro SD card with Raspbian stretch 2018apr image for Rpi2B and Wifi Dongle*

[image: rpi2b and wifi dongle]

*Checking out if Rpi2B Raspbian stretch 2019apr can detect TP-LINK TL-WN727N*

I found the setup can detect the TP-LINK Wifi dongle.  I remember I needed to google a list of dongles that Rpi can detect.  So I would suggest you to check that out by the command ***lsusb***.  If you can detect the dongle, then you are almost there! :)

[image: tplink wifi adapter]

*Entering Wifi SSID and password at desktop*

setting up Wifi in desktop is even easier.  The steps are listed below.

> 1. Select your Wifi country (otherwise top right network icon won't work).
> 2. At top right corner, click the double red cross icon (Wifi and Ethernet).
> 3. Select to turn on your network in the list (my network name is tlfong01).
> 4. Enter password (pre shared key).

That is all.

Good luck.

[image: wifi password]

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***The paragraphs below are out of date and need to be modified and/or deleted***, after I have completed the answer above.

---

Let me see.

I am using Rpi3B+ and Raspbian 2019apr.

When you are configuring WiFi under terminal mode, you should have gone through the last couple of steps as shown below:

[image: wifi config 1]

[image: wifi config 2]

[image: wifi config 3]

[image: wifi config 4]

***You must enter the correct ssid and passphrase***, otherwise you will get the N2 Wi-fi error message.

The "ssid" and "passphrase" should be the same for your other WiFi devices, such as your mobile phone.  You might like to try your ssid and passphrase with your mobile phone first, to make sure they are OK.

And perhaps you forgot to ***switch on your router***? :)

Comment: my router is usually on, and when i go to do what you said, I get the errors shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Raspberry Pi **2B**. This model does not have an on-board WiFi device so it does not make sense to enable WiFi with **raspi-config**. It seems this results in the error message you reported.

Comment: I am using an Edimax wifi adapter attached through a usb port.

Comment: @Mooshroom14 That is a very important detail! Please edit your question and complete it with this information.

Comment: Just edited this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after installing OMV5 with raspbian desktop version. I then uninstalled OMV5 but this problem arised...

The problem in my case, had to do with `dhcpcd` service being missing, not being able to get an IP. You can check if it is available with the next command.

```
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo service --status-all
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  cgroupfs-mount
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  dhcpcd
 [ + ]  docker
 [ + ]  dphys-swapfile
 [ + ]  fake-hwclock
 [ - ]  fio
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lightdm
 [ - ]  mdadm
 [ - ]  mdadm-waitidle
 [ + ]  monit
 [ + ]  networking
 [ - ]  nfs-common
 [ + ]  nginx
 [ - ]  paxctld
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  postfix
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  quota
 [ - ]  quotarpc
 [ + ]  raspi-config
 [ ? ]  rng-tools
 [ - ]  rpcbind
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ + ]  triggerhappy
 [ + ]  udev
 [ - ]  udhcpd
 [ + ]  watchdog
 [ - ]  wd_keepalive
 [ - ]  x11-common
 [ + ]  zerotier-one
```

Next, I configured my raspberry with a static IP to have network connectivity. Assuming you are using WIFI interface and you have a valid confguration on /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d -iwlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.143 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 wlan0
sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
```

You can also use eth0 interface and skip wpa_supplicant step.

And finally, I installed dhcpcd

```
sudo apt install dhcpcd5
```

After I reboot the Raspberry Pi, Wi-Fi manager plugin and `raspi-config` worked again.

**Check also these links:**

https://stevessmarthomeguide.com/configuring-networking-raspberry-pi/

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/37921#37921)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

https://www.howtogeek.com/118337/stupid-geek-tricks-change-your-ip-address-from-the-command-line-in-linux/